# DataGridView strange layout in upper-left corner

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tabcontrol

I've a strange layout problem in my C# Windows Forms Application using the [Metro Framework](https://github.com/thielj/MetroFramework).

There is a DataGridView docked inside of an tabControl. In the upper-left corner appears a gray strip.

[image: Upperleft corner]

When I click on it it disappears.

[image: Upperleft on hover]

Does anyone knows how to remove this?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to bring the DataGridView to the front calling the `BringToFront()` method after having added it to the tabpage. No need to play with the `Dock` property. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem. And i found this solution.
I had set the datagridview dock property to fill-inside the tabpage.
I then set dock property to left in place of fill and set the datagridview size to 1000,1000.(although it will by default set the height)
And the problem is solved.
I guess this gray linings appear because of sizing issue. Also does not appear in every tab page.. strange... but finally i got the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've changed the dock property to left, and changed the size of it, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is pretty late but I faced the same issue and found out that setting the Padding Property of the Tabpage to 3; 3; 3; 3 fixes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change Tabpage Padding to 3,3,3,3
then you call DataGrideView1.BringToFront(); at form load, works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the sizing / layout issue for the grey area, you can fix it by setting the `VerticalScrollBarsize` property to `0` and `VerticalScrollbar` property to `False`.